# Pause and Resume feature in an Audio Recorder Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing an audio recorder app on Universal Windows Platform on Windows 10 and the problem I'm facing is that when I resume the audio recording after it has been paused it only captures noise(like when the transformers shape shift kind of noise) and not the actual sound. Only the part when the recording is resumed after pause has this problem. I'm using `MediaCapture` class for this. Following is the code I've used to create the various functionalities.

```
//Start the recording

private async void recordBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{     
    await CaptureMedia.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, file); //Records the audio to the specified file                           
}

//Pause the audio recording

private async void pauseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{     
    await CaptureMedia.PauseRecordAsync(Windows.Media.Devices.MediaCapturePauseBehavior.RetainHardwareResources); // Pauses the recording

}

//Resume the audio recording

private async void resumeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{     
   await CaptureMedia.ResumeRecordAsync(); // Everyting captured after this is just noise not the actual voice or sound

}
```

`encodingProfile` is a class field and it is initialized in the constructor to record the audio as a high quality mp3.

```
public Recorder()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
}
```

The device I'm running this app on is a Windows 10 desktop and I'm using an external USB Microphone for recording.

Comment: Can you share how you're creating your `encodingProfile`, and what device you're running this on?

Comment: I'm running the app on a windows 10 desktop, also I've added the piece where I create the `encodingProfile`